# Does Gallina have holes like in Agda?

Tags: coq

When proving in Coq, it's nice to be able to prove one little piece at a time, and have Coq help keep track of the obligations.

```
Theorem ModusPonens: forall (A B : Prop), ((A -> B) /\ A) -> B.
Proof.
  intros A B [H1 H2].
  apply H1.
```

At this point I can see the proof state to know what is required to finish the proof:

```
context
H2: B
------
goal: B
```

But when writing Gallina, do we have to solve the whole thing in one bang, or make lots of little helper functions? I'd love to be able to put use a question mark to ask Coq what it's looking for:

```
Definition ModusPonens' := fun (A B : Prop) (H : (A -> B) /\ A) =>
  match H with
    | conj H1 H2 => H1 {?} (* hole of type B *)
  end.
```

It really seems like Coq should be able to do this, because I can even put ltac in there and Coq will find what it needs:

```
Definition ModusPonens' := fun (A B : Prop) (H : (A -> B) /\ A) =>
  match H with
    | conj H1 H2 => H1 ltac:(assumption)
  end.
```

If Coq is smart enough to finish writing the definition for me, it's probably smart enough to tell me what I need to write in order to finish the function myself, at least in simple cases like this.

So how do I do this? Does Coq have this kind of feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `refine` for this.  You can write underscores which will turn into obligations for you to solve later.

```
Definition ModusPonens: forall (A B : Prop), ((A -> B) /\ A) -> B.

    refine (fun A B H =>
              match H with
                 | conj H1 H2 => H1 _ (* hole of type A *)
               end).
```

Now your goal is to provide an `A`. This can be discharged with `exact H2. Defined.`

Comment: I noticed I could keep the definition transparent / unfoldable by using "Definition" instead of "Theorem". Could I make the edit to your answer?

Comment: Is there a way to finish off the proof/definition in a computational rather than logical way? I noticed that after the `.` (dot), I can finish off the proof with `assumption`, but is there a way to do it without tactics / in Gallina?

Comment: Yes! Go ahead please!

Comment: The transparency of the definition is more related to whether you end proof mode with `Defined.` instead of `Qed.` than to what keyword you use to start the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Use an underscore

```
Definition ModusPonens' := fun (A B : Prop) (H : (A -> B) /\ A) =>
  match H with
    | conj H1 H2 => H1 _ (* hole of type A *)
  end.

(*
Error: Cannot infer this placeholder of type
"A" in environment:
A, B : Prop
H : (A -> B) /\ A
H1 : A -> B
H2 : A
*)
```

or use `Program`

```
Require Import Program.
Obligation Tactic := idtac.  (* By default Program tries to be smart and solve simple obligations automatically. This commands disables it. *)

Program Definition ModusPonens' := fun (A B : Prop) (H : (A -> B) /\ A) =>
  match H with
    | conj H1 H2 => H1 _ (* hole of type A *)
  end.

Next Obligation. intros. (* See the type of the hole *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could mark both answer correct, as they both enable the kind of workflow I'm looking for!